# How to display the slider inside the container and end till viewport

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, flickity

I am using [flickity slider](https://flickity.metafizzy.co/) and it's working. What I am doing is, I have to start my slider from my heading like below image

[image]

and when it's slide then it will go to the left side till viewport.

[image]

I tried below code.

```js
$('.main-carousel').flickity({
  freeScroll: true,
  cellAlign: 'left',
  wrapAround: true,
  contain: true,
  prevNextButtons: false,
  pageDots: true,
  draggable: false
});
```

```css
.headingwrap {
  margin-left: 10%;
}

.carousel-cell {
  width: 30%;
  height: 250px;
}

.one {
  background-color: red
}

.two {
  background-color: green
}

.three {
  background-color: orange
}

.four {
  background-color: blue
}

.five {
  background-color: black
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flickity/2.2.1/flickity.min.css">
<section>
  <div class="headingwrap">
    <h2>This is the heading </h2>
  </div>
  <div class="main-carousel">
    <div class="carousel-cell one"></div>
    <div class="carousel-cell two"></div>
    <div class="carousel-cell three"></div>
    <div class="carousel-cell four"></div>
    <div class="carousel-cell five"></div>
  </div>

</section>



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flickity/2.2.1/flickity.pkgd.min.js"></script>
```

This is second snippet and just added

```
.flickity-viewport{margin-left: 10%;}
```

```js
$('.main-carousel').flickity({
  freeScroll: true,
  cellAlign: 'left',
  wrapAround: true,
  contain: true,
  prevNextButtons: false,
  pageDots: true,
  draggable: false
});
```

```css
.flickity-viewport {
  margin-left: 10%;
}

.headingwrap {
  margin-left: 10%;
}

.carousel-cell {
  width: 25%;
  height: 250px;
}

.one {
  background-color: red
}

.two {
  background-color: green
}

.three {
  background-color: orange
}

.four {
  background-color: blue
}

.five {
  background-color: black
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flickity/2.2.1/flickity.min.css">
<section>
  <div class="headingwrap">
    <h2>This is the heading </h2>
  </div>
  <div class="main-carousel">
    <div class="carousel-cell one"></div>
    <div class="carousel-cell two"></div>
    <div class="carousel-cell three"></div>
    <div class="carousel-cell four"></div>
    <div class="carousel-cell five"></div>
  </div>

</section>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flickity/2.2.1/flickity.pkgd.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I didn't understand what you want.Can you please explain more about the problem you are facing while implementing this?

Comment: @RishabTyagi, Check my first image when page load then it will display like that and when slide then it will display live second image.

Comment: @RishabTyagi, In my code slider, is working as my expected but on page load how can i show my slider below the heading?(Refer image one)

Comment: You can increase the size of the slide or use smaller heading like h4.

Comment: @RishabTyagi, I think you havn't undersood my question.

Comment: @RishabTyagi, I added my second snippet. When page load then it is below the heading but notice if I slide then it not doing to left side live my second image in the question.

Comment: So, you want to shift the slide to the left after page load.

Comment: @RishabTyagi, Not shift, I have to slide to the left. If you notice, in the second snippet. it's not doing to the end because of margin left 10%

Comment: @RishabTyagi, If I remove these three options ( cellAlign: 'left', wrapAround: true, contain: true) then it's working but getting lots of space on the left side. Refer link https://prnt.sc/trnm6g

Comment: You should  try margin-left in negative values.for e.g. `margin-left:-15%;`

Comment: @RishabTyagi, Where I have to add this css? I mean class name

Comment: Add this in your `.main-carousel{}` class to remove the extra white space after removing those three options.

Comment: @RishabTyagi, Sorry it's not working

Comment: I added .flickity-slider {margin-left: 11.5%;} and I got my soution.

Comment: Very nice.Good job.